# Check if string contains only digits

Tags: javascript, numbers, digits

I want to check if a `string` contains only digits. I used this:

```
var isANumber = isNaN(theValue) === false;

if (isANumber){
    ..
}
```

But realized that it also allows `+` and `-`. Basically, I want to make sure an `input` contains ONLY digits and no other characters. Since `+100` and `-5` are both numbers, `isNaN()` is not the right way to go.
Perhaps a regexp is what I need? Any tips?

Answer (score 1052, accepted):

how about

```js
let isnum = /^\d+$/.test(val);
```

Comment: This is great! I am curious does \d not refer to digit that is decimal?

Comment: @dewwwald: Some languages implement it differently, but in JavaScript, `\d` is *exactly* equivalent to `[0-9]`.

Comment: [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp)  you can find documentation about how `Regular Expressions` work

Comment: **`/^\d*$/` instead**, if you find an empty string _containing only digits_.

Comment: @DrorBar I’m sorry for my poor English and let me rephrase it: “if you consider an empty string to be _having only digits_.”

Comment: This solution is good, but it's true for things like `000000001`

Comment: is test inbuilt JS method ?

Comment: @vikramvi yes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Comment: what if it has decemaks

Comment: If you are wondering about performance, I made a quick benchmark with the answers to OP's question : https://jsben.ch/pdsSd
My results : the regex is the fastest method (from x5 to x20) in all browsers except in Safari where CharCodeAt is 10% faster.

Comment: Sorry, I came here because I'm lazy.

Comment: If you want to extract the expression to a variable for using it in a loop, then be careful - you should also do `regex.lastIndex = 0` before each `regex.test(...)`.

Answer (score 99):

```
string.match(/^[0-9]+$/) != null;
```

Answer (score 24):

```
String.prototype.isNumber = function(){return /^\d+$/.test(this);}
console.log("123123".isNumber()); // outputs true
console.log("+12".isNumber()); // outputs false
```

Comment: It's considered bad practice in Javascript to modify prototypes of built-in objects (principle of least surprise, and potential conflicts in future ECMA versions) - consider `isNumber = () => /^\d+$/.test(this);` instead, and use as `console.log(isNumber("123123));`

Comment: FWIW, in 2009 when this answer was posted, it was not yet considered a bad practice. Several jQuery competitors that existed then, before jQuery had yet to win out, all practiced prototype extensions.

Comment: still, it was a bad practice, even though it wasn't considered as such by jQuery lovers.

Answer (score 22):

If you want to even support for float values (Dot separated values) then you can use this expression :

```
var isNumber = /^\d+\.\d+$/.test(value);
```

Comment: however if you don't use a float rather int it will return false maybe using "?" after ".\" solved that. I suggest this /^\d+[\.,\,]?\d+$/.test(value) to allow both comma and point decimal (later maybe can transform comma to point)

Comment: @Lucke, the regex you suggested will only be able to find numbers with a decimal or higher than 9. If you change the first `\d+` to `\d*?`, it will be able to match 0 - 9, as well as numbers such as .333

Comment: Close: ```var isNumber = /^\d*\.?\d+$/.test(value)``` -- matches '3.5', '.5', '3' -- does not match '3.'

Comment: Since 2009, this question was always asking how to validate that a string contains only numbers.  This post is the correct answer to a different question.

Comment: @PeterHollingsworth This doesn't match negative numbers like `-100.2`

Answer (score 19):

Here's another interesting, readable way to check if a string contains only digits.

This method works by splitting the string into an array using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), and then uses the [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method to test whether all elements (characters) in the array [are included](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) in the string of digits `'0123456789'`:

```js
const digits_only = string => [...string].every(c => '0123456789'.includes(c));

console.log(digits_only('123')); // true
console.log(digits_only('+123')); // false
console.log(digits_only('-123')); // false
console.log(digits_only('123.')); // false
console.log(digits_only('.123')); // false
console.log(digits_only('123.0')); // false
console.log(digits_only('0.123')); // false
console.log(digits_only('Hello, world!')); // false
```

Comment: This will also return `true` for empty string `''`, and an empty array `[]`, an array of integers `[1, 2, 3]` (once they are < 10). It's more prone to bugs/misuse than the basic regular expression `/^\d+$/` I think

Comment: This is far easier to read than a Regex, and is easily expandable to other approaches. When used in TypeScript, and in conjunction with length checks, this can be very elegant.

Comment: I like its uniqueness, but also, this solution is most “resource consuming“ to use and not scalable in performance intensive or data heavy client-side, due to requiring 10x operations for every character of input.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a solution without using regular expressions:

```
function onlyDigits(s) {
  for (let i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const d = s.charCodeAt(i);
    if (d < 48 || d > 57) return false
  }
  return true
}
```

where 48 and 57 are the char codes for "0" and "9", respectively.

Answer (score 10):

This is what you want

```
function isANumber(str){
  return !/\D/.test(str);
}
```

Comment: This answer allows an empty string to pass as a valid number.

Answer (score 8):

in case you need integer and float at same validation

`/^\d+\.\d+$|^\d+$/.test(val)`

Comment: Since 2009, this question was always asking how to validate that a string contains only numbers.  This post is the correct answer to a different question.

Answer (score 5):

```
function isNumeric(x) {
    return parseFloat(x).toString() === x.toString();
}
```

Though this will return `false` on strings with leading or trailing zeroes.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can use the following regex:

```
^\d+$
```

Comment: Does not work for floating point numbers.

Comment: Well, floating point numbers don't only contain digits. They may very well also include a decimal point. And since the question was about digits instead of things that can be parsed as a number, the answer stands.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to include float values also you can use the following code

```
theValue=$('#balanceinput').val();
var isnum1 = /^\d*\.?\d+$/.test(theValue);
var isnum2 =  /^\d*\.?\d+$/.test(theValue.split("").reverse().join(""));
alert(isnum1+' '+isnum2);
```

this will test for only digits and digits separated with '.' the first test will cover values such as 0.1 and 0 but also .1 , 
it will not allow 0.  so the solution that I propose is to reverse theValue so .1 will be 1. then the same regular expression will not allow it .

example :

```
 theValue=3.4; //isnum1=true , isnum2=true 
theValue=.4; //isnum1=true , isnum2=false 
theValue=3.; //isnum1=flase , isnum2=true
```

Comment: Since 2009, this question was always asking how to validate that a string contains only numbers.  This post is the correct answer to a different question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery:

```
$.isNumeric('1234'); // true
$.isNumeric('1ab4'); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave room for `.` you can try the below regex.

```
/[^0-9.]/g
```

Answer (score -1):

## Here's a Solution without using regex

```js
const  isdigit=(value)=>{
    const val=Number(value)?true:false
    console.log(val);
    return val
}

isdigit("10")//true
isdigit("any String")//false
```

Comment: for 0 it would be false

Comment: For 0x123 would be true :/

Comment: any number with a space at the end will evaluate to true

Answer (score -2):

```
c="123".match(/\D/) == null #true
c="a12".match(/\D/) == null #false
```

If a string contains only digits it will return null