# Javascript: Validate a field: Not empty & only contains numbers

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validate numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)

Hi I am trying to validate a field using javascript to ensure that the field is not empty AND only contains numbers

I am using document.getElementById to get the value of the field, then using this function to validate it:

```
function isNumeric(elem, message, messsage2)
{
   if(isNaN(elem))
   { 
    alert(message2); 
    return false; 
   }
   else if (elem == null || elem =="")
   {
    alert(message);
    return false;
   }
return true;
}
```

However this function still allows me to enter letters as where there should be numbers

Comment: do you think you are the first person trying to validate number with javascript in 2012? :) see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1779013/944681) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18082/944681)

Comment: both those posts are validating numbers, i need a function that validates not empty and only numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
function isNonEmptyNumber (str) {
  if(!str.length) return false;
  var num = +str;
  return isFinite(num) && !isNaN(num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With regexp:

```
value.match(/^\d+$/)
```

Comment: This will fail to match numbers like `1.2`, `-1`, etc.

Comment: Yes, but then you'd get false positives like `+++++` or `.`