# Filtering numbers out from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, filter

I have an array like below and need to filter out the numbers from it ex: `[1,2]`

```
var str = [
  "https://xx.jpg",
  "https://xx.jpg",
  "1",
  "https://guide.jpg",
  "2", 
  "/static.jpg"
]
```

I have the below code :

```
var filtered = str.filter(function(item) {
  return (typeof item === "number")
});
```

but it is not filtering as it is a string.

How to do it?

Comment: you have strings, not numbers in the array.

Comment: `digit`? you serious? What's `res`?

Comment: Did you even check on internet how to check if a string is a number ?

Comment: I would ask that you learn what the basic types of JavaScript are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [**Check if string contains only digits**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779013/check-if-string-contains-only-digits)

Comment: @Fran surely this question is the negated version of that?

Comment: @ambili - what is the desired outcome?

Comment: @evolutionxbox - The linked answer checks for digits, is that not what would allow OP to determine which ones are numbers? See other answers using that exact expression only negating it. Negating or not is up to OP, still same expression as in linked answer I think, no?

Comment: You can use `str.filter(Number)`

Answer (score 21):

I think this is the most precise way to filter out numbers from an array.

```
str.filter(Number);
```

If the array contains a number in the form of string, then the resulting array will have the number in the form of string. In your case, the resulting array will be ["1", "2"].

If the original array contains 0 or "0", then they will not be present in the resulting array.

If resulting array should include only integer numbers,

```
str.filter(Number.isInteger)
```

This will exclude the number in the form of string like "1", "2", etc.

For both integer and float numbers,

```
str.filter(Number.isFinite)
```

Comment: I was just about to write the same. this should be the top answer.

Comment: This will exclude `"0"` because 0 is a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value

Comment: filter(Number) will except zeros, you should use filter(Number.isInteger)

Comment: @аlexdykyі filter(Number.isInteger) will exclude all the integer values like "1", "3",etc in array as well.

Answer (score 10):

Making a small change to your code to make it work, this might possibly work.

```js
var str = ["https://xx.jpg", "https://xx.jpg", "1", "https://guide.jpg", "2", "/static.jpg"];
var filtered = str.filter(function (item) {
  return !(parseInt(item) == item);
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Or if you want the numbers:

```js
var str = ["https://xx.jpg", "https://xx.jpg", "1", "https://guide.jpg", "2", "/static.jpg"];
var filtered = str.filter(function (item) {
  return (parseInt(item) == item);
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: The question asks us to filter out numbers, so 1.5 should be filtered out as well.

Comment: You are right, parseInt(1.5) returns 1, I thought it returns NaN. My bad

Comment: I really don't understand why people would like to downvote!

Comment: I think you should not care. I upvoted your answer when I was convinced it is correct. My answer was not upvoted, nor downvoted. I am regularly downvoted as well when I am convinced I have given a correct answer, but this will not stop me from helping.

Comment: @LajosArpad Agreed. Just curious to know why.

Answer (score 3):

Use [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

```js
var str=["https://xx.jpg","https://xx.jpg","1","https://guide.jpg","2","/static.jpg"];

var filtered = str.filter(function(item) {
     
     return (!isNaN(item)); 
     });
     
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: "1" and "2" should be filtered out instead of the other items, you need isNaN instead of !isNaN. Also, your answer does not address the case of "" or null.

Answer (score 3):

```
var str = ["https://xx.jpg","https://xx.jpg","1","https://guide.jpg","2", "/static.jpg" ]
str.filter(item=>!isNaN(parseInt(item)))
```

parseInt convert number to integer and other values converted to "NaN", isNaN function validate value is either "NaN" or not

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: this answer worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression which test a string, if it contains only digits.

```js
var array = ["https://xx.jpg", "https://xx.jpg", "1", "https://guide.jpg", "2", "/static.jpg"];

array = array.filter(function (a) {
    return !/^\d+$/.test(a);
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a string only contains numeric digits, you can use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

```js
var str = ["https://xx.jpg", "https://xx.jpg", "1", "https://guide.jpg", "2", "/static.jpg"];
var filtered = str.filter(function (item) {
  return item.match(/^-?\d+$/);
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const intArray = [];
const strArray = [];
const rest_test_parameters = (...args) => {

  args.filter((item) => {
    if (parseInt(item)) {
      return intArray.push(parseInt(item));
    }
    strArray.push(item);
  });
};
const objects = {
  a: "a",
  b: "c"
};
rest_test_parameters(1, 2, "99","hello", objects);
console.log("intArray", intArray);
console.log("strArray",strArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You usage func helper in filter

```
 function isNumber(n) {  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.filter(function(item) {
    return (item !== 0) && ((!item) || (isNaN(item)));
});
```

The right side of the operation calls `filter` and passes a `function` which returns `true` if an item is not 0 and it is either falsey or not a number; otherwise it returns `false`. For instance `""` or `null` should be kept in the array as far as the specification goes. With this approach we get the desired array and we assign it to the `str` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const filterNumbers = [123456789, 'limit', 'elite', 987654321, 'destruction', 'present'];

const result = filterNumbers.filter(number => parseInt(number) == number);

console.log(result);
```

Here's similar code that returns the number instead of the string. The `=>` is just alternative syntax for `function` and `return` (see [arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)), but will yield the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the above answers are good, but missing one thing; **filtering out array of numbers**(neither integer, nor string form of numbers).

I haved added the snippet to address those little issues.

```js
var str = ["https://xx.jpg", "https://xx.jpg", "1", "https://guide.jpg", "2.4", "/static.jpg","4"];
var filteredNumbers = str.filter(item=> parseFloat(item) == item).map(item=>parseFloat(item));
console.log(filteredNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner:
`arr.filter(n => (parseInt(n)===0 || +n)).map(Number)`

This is assuming it is a flat array and not a nested one.