# Array reduce concat instead of sum values

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying the first time to use google sheets and the script to sum a column of values and place the sum in the first free cell with a date.

Unfortunately I get a string and not the Sum I'm expecting.

Do you have any clue?

Thanks

KR

```
function sommami() {
  var foglioAssets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Assets');
  Logger.log(foglioAssets)
  var colonnaP = foglioAssets.getRange('P2:P100');
  Logger.log(colonnaP);
  var array = colonnaP.getValues()
  Logger.log(array)
    var somma = array.reduce(function(a,b) {
      return a+b});
  Logger.log(somma);
  var foglioHistoricalNW = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('HistoricalNW');
  Logger.log(foglioHistoricalNW)
  var primaRigaLibera = foglioHistoricalNW.getRange('A:A').getValues().length + 1;
  Logger.log(primaRigaLibera)
  var data = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");
  Logger.log(data)
  foglioHistoricalNW.getRange('A' + primaRigaLibera).setValue(data);
  foglioHistoricalNW.getRange('B' + primaRigaLibera).setValue(somma);
}
```

> 17:15:04  Notifica    Esecuzione avviata
> 17:15:04    Informazioni    Sheet
> 17:15:04    Informazioni    Range
> 17:15:04    Informazioni    [[596.38], [17515.15], [29.79], [369.02], [], [6829.2], [12082.0], [14991.0], [], [300000.0], [32000.0], [18500.0], [], [19971.99], [35820.104140799995], [], [-162547.23], [-48500.0], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
> 17:15:04    Informazioni    596.3817515.1529.79369.026829.21208214991300000320001850019971.9935820.104140799995-162547.23-48500
> 17:15:04    Informazioni    Sheet
> 17:15:04    Informazioni    6.0
> 17:15:04    Informazioni    19/02/2024
> 17:15:05    Notifica    Esecuzione completata

I've tried multiple things but nothing worked

Comment: I would recommend adding a `Logger.log()` within your function used for `reduce()` to confirm the numbers it is adding up. It _should_ work. Make sure they are actual number format and not pieces of text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Add .flat() and .filter(Number) to Get the Correct Sum

I have observed that in:

```
var array = colonnaP.getValues()
  Logger.log(array)
    var somma = array.reduce(function(a,b) {
      return a+b});
  Logger.log(somma);
```

You did not take into account that the array returned by `getValues()` is 2-dimensional. In order for you to use the `reduce()` function correctly, you must flatten the array into 1 dimension by using `flat()`. You must then use `.filter(Number)` in order for you to only extract all numerical values to be summed. With this, you should replace:

```
var array = colonnaP.getValues()
```

with:

```
var array = colonnaP.getValues().flat().filter(Number);
```

### Test

Using a modified version of the first half of your code and placing random numbers on column P:

```
function sommami() {
  var foglioAssets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Assets');
  Logger.log(foglioAssets)
  var colonnaP = foglioAssets.getRange('P2:P100');
  Logger.log(colonnaP);
  //Add flat() since the array produced by getValues() is 2 dimensional
  //Add filter(Number) to get only the number values to add
  var array = colonnaP.getValues().flat().filter(Number);
  Logger.log(array)
  var somma = array.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a + b
  });
  Logger.log(somma);
}
```

I got the following output:

[image]

### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- [filter(Number)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44628965/filtering-numbers-out-from-an-array)

Comment: Feel free to ask anything about the answer posted above. Please do take note that I only used half of your code since I checked that the cause of `getting a string and not the sum you expected` is just the error in the first half.

Comment: That worked thanks. I'm just trying to learn how to use this app scripts but I've not found simple for beginners guide or wiki... Could you give me some tips how to start from zero? Thanks

Comment: You can actually start by watching tutorials on YouTube. From there, you may read the Google Apps Script Developers Guide like [this one for sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets). Also, JavaScript tutorials are also helpful since Google Apps Script is close to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
function sommami() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Assets');
  var rg = sh.getRange('P2:P100');
  var vs = rg.getValues().flat();
  var somma = vs.reduce((a,v,i) => (a += v, a));
  var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('HistoricalNW');
  var len = sh1.getRange('A1:A'+ sh1.getLastRow()).getValues().length + 1;
  var data = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");
  sh1.getRange('A' + len).setValue(data);
  sh1.getRange('B' + len).setValue(sum);
}
```