# Angular 6 custom validators how to ban user from adding special characters like + or - to a number input

Tags: angular, angular6, customvalidator

I made an angular 6 custom validators to check if a user entered the 3 required digits or not. Here is my input:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" color="warn">
     <mat-label>Last 3 digits</mat-label>
     <input matInput type="text" formControlName="last_three_digits" placeholder="Last 3 digits">
</mat-form-field>&nbsp;
```

And here is how I declare it in reactive form:

```
  'last_three_digits': new FormControl('', [Validators.required, validatePositiveNotNull, validateLengthThree])
```

I tried to add `Validators.pattern("[0-9 ]*")` but it keep letting the user to add `-` or `+` or `=` or `/`.

I just need to strict into number of length = 3.

Here is the script:

```
export function validateLengthThree(control: AbstractControl)
{
  if(control.value==null || control.value==undefined)
  {
    return { validPositive: true}
  }
  else if(control.value.length<3 && control.value!=null && control.value!=undefined)
  {
    return { validPositive: true}
  }
  else if(control.value.length>3)
  {
    return { validPositive: true}
  }
  return null;
}
```

I tried to change the type of input to `number` but still the same.

I used this pattern `/^\d+$/` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779013/check-if-string-contains-only-digits?answertab=active#tab-top) on stack, and the input still accepting the special characters and validating the form.

P.S. I added the `null` and `undefined` conditions in my custom validators, because when I focus out from this input, and while it's empty, it throw an error saying that it can't run on null values.

Answer (score 1):

use a directive on your input, to prevent the key pressed

107 = "+"

109 = "-"

111 = "/"

187 = "="

```
<input keysban="[107,109,111,187]" type="text">
```

the directive

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[editable]'
})
export class EditableDirective {
  @Input() keysban: number[];

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    // check banned key
    if (this.keysban) {
      if (this.keysban.indexOf(event.keyCode) > -1) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
    console.log(event.keyCode);
  }

  constructor() { }

}
```

don't forget to add your max length validator