# How can we understand if the value inside a String is an int or not in Python?

Tags: python, types, type-conversion

I am writing a code where I am facing the problem and need a solution if it exists.
Suppose we have a following String type variable in Python which contains an integer value.
Eg:`x='123'`
I know that we can easily convert this by type conversion to int.
However, suppose we have the following list.

```
x=['123','Spain']
```

Is there any method in Python by which I can know which element of the list x is Integer contained inside a string and which is purely an Object?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal

Comment: What should the output be, given your `x`?

Comment: Yes, there is a method. Please provide a sample input with e.g. 5 values and expected output (it is not clear if you mean items, indices, ...)

Comment: Thanks! I got what I needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend this method:

```py
x = "123"
if x.isdigit():
    # int
elif x.replace(".","",1).isdigit():
    # float
else:
    # str
```

Comment: `elif x.replace(".","").isdigit():` this I don't like, consider e.g. `"1.2.3"`. Is it float?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have similar question with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859282/check-if-a-string-contains-a-number).

But, from my perspective, for more general solution (language agnostic), you should learn more about Regular Expression, here also [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779013/check-if-string-contains-only-digits)