# How to prevent user from typing numbers in input?

Tags: javascript

I wanna put the check (if) before user can type his name, but it doesn't work. I can still put numbers in the input.
What's wrong?

```js
var name1 = prompt('enter name');
var surname = prompt('enter surname');
var patronymic = prompt('enter secondname');
var fullName = name1 + " " + surname + " " + patronymic;


if (typeof(name1) === "number" || typeof(surname) === "number"|| typeof(patronymic) === "number") {
    do {
        alert('wrong, try again');
        name1 = prompt('enter name');
        surname = prompt('enter surname');
        patronymic = prompt('enter ');
    }
    while (typeof(name1) === "string" && typeof(surname) === "string" && typeof(patronymic) === "string");
}

alert("U " + fullName);
```

Comment: prompts return will never be a number

Comment: if(parseInt(name1) === "number")) doesnt work too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeof(name1) === "number"` would always be false as `name1` as prompt input string would always be string, if not empty (check propmt [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) for its return type). Please check this fix, we can use `regex` regular expression to check whether input is a number.

Please check the `isNumber` function and the comments.

```js
var name1 = prompt('enter name');
var surname = prompt('enter surname');
var patronymic = prompt('enter secondname');


// a function to check whether the input string is number
function isNumber(str) {
  return !!( // !! symbol is to cast a variable to be a boolean (true or false) value
    str && // check whether str is null, if it is then we'll return false, as null is not a number
    str.match(/^\d+$/)); // use regular expression to check whether the input only contains digits. Please check the reference posts in my answer for more information about regex
}

if (isNumber(name1) || isNumber(surname) || isNumber(patronymic)) {
  do {
    alert('wrong, try again');
    name1 = prompt('enter name');
    surname = prompt('enter surname');
    patronymic = prompt('enter ');
  }
  while (isNumber(name1) || isNumber(surname) || isNumber(patronymic));
}
var fullName = name1 + " " + surname + " " + patronymic;

alert("U " + fullName);
```

#### More Reference

- [Check if string contains only digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779013/check-if-string-contains-only-digits) for JavaScript
- [Regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: thanks, that works. But i have no idea what (--return !!(str && str.match(/^\d+$/));--) does tho :)
I just started learning JS today

Comment: @gunniq I added comments in  `isNumber` function, please take a look. Feel free to drop a message if you have more questions.

Comment: @gunniq regular expression is somehow not for first day learners, so if you feel the function is too hard you totally can skip it for now, it won't be a blocker to your JS learning journey ;) I'll suggest you to just take `isNumber` function as a black box for now

Comment: last question, can i replace my if's with questionmark anywhre in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Prompt always return a string. If you entered a number it is also return to the variable as a string

You can use the following method to check for numbers in a string.

```
var name = prompt('Enter');
isNaN(Number(name)) //this will return false if name is a number
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular Expression to check numbers.

```
var name1;
var surname;
var patronymic;
name1= prompt('enter name');
while(/\d/.test(name1)){
    alert('wrong, try again');
    name1= prompt('enter name');
}
surname = prompt('enter surname');
while(/\d/.test(surname)){
    alert('wrong, try again');
    surname= prompt('enter surname');
}
patronymic = prompt('enter secondname');
while(/\d/.test(patronymic)){
    alert('wrong, try again');
    patronymic= prompt('enter secondname');
}
var fullName = name1 + " " + surname + " " + patronymic;
alert("U " + fullName);
```