# convert strings to numbers depending on whether they have a suffix eg 1.5K

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an updateable list

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="one">posts <span class="num_1">1</span></a>
    <a class="two">followers <span class="num_2">999</span></a>
    <a class="three">following <span class="num_3">1K</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>

<button class="post-btn">Post</button>
<button class="follow-btn">Follow</button>
```

if a user updates the list by clicking either button and the number is below 1000, i want to get the text and add or subtract 1. if the number is above 1000, hence 1K, i want nothing to happen. all i have so far is this code which works for numbers under 1000 and not numbers abbbreviated as 1K

`$('.num_1').text(Number($('.num_1').text())+1);` or `$('.num_1').text(Number($('.num_1').text())-1);`

any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: *if the number is above 1000, hence 1K, i want nothing to happen. all i have so far is this code which works for numbers under 1000 and not numbers abbbreviated as 1K?*....contradictory requirements!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if string contains only digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779013/check-if-string-contains-only-digits)

Comment: you will also need to multiply the number by 1000, if there is a **K** in the line. And after that, do the check.

Comment: Translating the postfixes `k`, `m` or `g` (for "kilo", "mega" and "giga") is not so complicated, but unfortunately, that won't be enough if you want to then imcrement these values. You would need to have all digits of these number available, otherwise the incrementation will not be successful.

Comment: @freedomn-m yes thanks that helps

Answer (score 1):

The numeric value of strings such as `"1k"` or `"1m"` is `NaN`.

Therefore, you may use `Number.isNaN` method to determine whether the string should be updated.
for example:

```js
function increase (elem) {
    var previousValue = Number(elem.text());
    if (!Number.isNaN(previousValue)) {
        elem.text(previousValue + 1);
    }
}

increase($('.num_1'))
```

Comment: decided to just update with AJAX instead, thank you