# What is the best way to validate if a prompt entry is a number in JS?

Tags: javascript, numbers

JS turns all prompt input into a string. I'd like to test if it is an actual number and if yes, turn the type into a number. What's the best way to do it? If I use `Number(target)`, it turns any string into a `number` type too.

```
    var res = prompt('How long'); //input: "ABC" 
    typeof Number(res)
    >> "number"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779013/check-if-string-contains-only-digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// let res = +(prompt('How long') // + convert to number
if(res = +(prompt('How long'))){
  console.log('Its number : ', res);
}else{
  console.log("Its not a number");
}
```

Comment: thanks! i'd ever think of this solution

Comment: @somniumm Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, if it solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can take help of regex

```
let isNum = /^\d+$/.test(res);
```

the result in `isNum` will either be true or false depending on your input. if the result is true then you can convert it to number

```
if (isNum)
  let num = parseInt(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to reach that but one of the best practices is:

First, get the input:

```
let result = prompt('How long');
```

Convert input to number:

```
let resultNumber = Number(result);
```

Now, time to validate our `resultNumber`:

```
if(!Number.isNaN(resultNumber)) {
  // It's a actual number  
} else {
  // It's not a number
}
```

**Note 1**: converting strings into numbers does not always produce numbers, `NaN` is the result of those converting, let's take an example

```
Number('false') // --> NaN
```

**Note 2**: If the number is an actual number so it is converted to a number type but in the case of `NaN` the `Number.isNaN()` will check it.